# Not Recognizing variable values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send values through an ajax call to a server. These variables, **user** and **token**, are being defined and assigned values in the javascript. When I debug I can see that the values in the part of the ajax code are not the values I am setting in an earlier part of the code (the variables **user** and **token**):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/post',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'user': user, 'token': token},
    .
    .
    .
```

but I am seeing the values in the code:

```
console.log('Access Token: ' + token);
console.log('user ID: ' + user);
```

Possible Scope issue?

Here is the code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#postform").on('submit', function(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           var user = "";
           var token = "";

           <!-- Add the Facebook SDK for Javascript -->
           (function(d, s, id){
                          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                          if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                          js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')
            );

            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
             FB.init({
                       appId            : '2643875785766686',
                       xfbml            : true,
                       version          : 'v17.0'
                    });
             FB.login(function(response) {
                  if (response.authResponse) {
                       FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name, userID'}, function(response) {
                           console.log('Good to see you');
                       });
                       FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                           if (response.status === 'connected') {
                               user = response.authResponse.userID;
                               token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                               console.log('Access Token: ' + token);
                               console.log('user ID: ' + user);
                           }
                       });
                  }
                  else {
                    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                  }
             });
            };
            $('#response').text("");
            $.ajax({
              url: '/post',
              type: 'POST',
              data: {'user': user, 'token': token},
              success: function (data) {
                 $('#response').text(data.response);
                 setTimeout(function(){
                    window.location.reload();
                 }, 5000);
                 // Hide button
                 $("#post").hide();
              },
            });
            // Clear the items
            $('#items').val('');
            // Clear file name
            $('#myFile').val('');
        });
    });
</script>
```